# stopPropagation is not working

Tags: jquery

It is not working,i need onclick base not id based code,please help me

```
<div onclick="favTheater(id)">
<img  src="#"/> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function favTheater(id){
        alert("dsfdsf"+id);
        var e = window.event;
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href="http://www.google.co.in/";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What's id ? What do you mean by "not working" ? There are other strange things than simply the stopPropagation here.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Are you actually submitting an id? BTW; onclick is deprecated as far as i know

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 3):

A few problems with your code :

- You're calling `favTheater(id)` on click but you didn't define an id,
- you're using `window.event`, which exists only on IE. Note also that those old IE browsers didn't have `stopPropagation` (it came with IE9),
- there is no reason to stop propagation or prevent default as you're replacing the page immediately with `http://www.google.co.in/`,
- as noticed by jerome.s, there would be nothing to propagate anyway as your div isn't in a clickable element,
- there isn't any default behavior to prevent (clicking on a div does nothing without specific handler), so `preventDefault` is useless.

So, your code is "not working", but it's hard to incriminate `stopPropagation`

Comment: And also there's no propagation to stop. Clicking on a div has no default event bound by the browser.